# Placing rectangular boxes in a bigger rectangular box

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I have certain rectangular boxes of different sizes and a bigger rectangular box. I need to fit in the maximum number of boxes of different categories possible in the bigger box. A certain minimum number of boxes of each category needs to accommodated in any case. Basically, I need to solve in the constraint optimisation problem. How do I proceed with this?

Comment: Are all boxes in the same category the same size?

Comment: If you decide to use a brute-force recursive approach in which you try placing the next box at each available location, then one way to shrink the solution space down without losing any optimal solutions is to constrain new box placements so that they must always be touching an existing box (or the wall of the containing box) on the left and bottom sides.  This works because any solution can be transformed into a solution where every box obeys this constraint by repeatedly shifting boxes left and down until no more such moves are possible.

Comment: Rectangular boxes are 2D or 3D?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, the left-and-bottom approach fails in the case of {2x2, 2x2, 1x6} in a 5x5 box.  Also consider {1x4, 1x4, 4x1, 4x1} in a 5x5 box with rotation not allowed.

Comment: @jwpat7: I don't yet see your 5x5 example -- could you list the top-left locations of each box in your optimal solution? Thanks. (But I don't think I believe you -- if your solution leaves a gap to the left of or below any box, then a solution of the same quality can be found by shifting that box to the left or down.)

Comment: For the {2x2, 2x2, 1x6} case, opposite-corner locations of the three rectangles can be (0,0),(2,2); (3,3),(5,5); and (0,4.243),(5, 0.757).  For the {1x4, 1x4, 4x1, 4x1} case, top-left locations are (0,5); (4,4); (0,1); (1,5)

Comment: the boxes are of different sizes and they are 3D

Comment: @jwpat7: Ah, I hadn't considered rotations besides 90 degrees! Your first example is quite right. Regarding your second one, though, it is possible to build your solution according to my constraints by adding the boxes in, for example, this order (I will list their top-left locations): (0,1); (0, 5); (4, 4); (1, 5). In fact any order in which (0, 1) comes first and (1, 5) does not come second satisfies my constraints.

Comment: @jwpat7: Also my 2nd comment is wrong in a different way: even under the assumption of only 90-degree rotations, it's obviously not true that obeying the "must-touch" constraint I suggest will cause all optimal solutions to be found -- whenever there is some slack, an infinite number of solutions will be missed.  But it is true that the optimal solution under the constraint will have the same quality (number and kind of boxes) as the optimal solution without the constraint, which is what's important.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no polynomial time algorithm for this problem, i.e. it's NP hard.

So try search. Sort the box from bigger to smaller may help.(by area or by one side, can't say which is better, depending on how you search).

If the speed is far from acceptable, try partical greedy to get a rather good solution.

Comment: Actually I am searching for an approximate solution as I know that the problem in NP-Hard. I cant seem to think of a way to proceed with the problem

Comment: Oh...I don't know then. If it's a real world problem, I suppose greedy would be good. Otherwise you may have a look at A Star(A*), try find some good evaluation function